# Error 1004 Methode PasteSpecial when copying with VBA with SendKeys

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I am writing a VBA code but is results in an error but when I manually debug with F8 then it works whitout a error.

> Error 1004, methode paste special from clase range failed

This is the code:

```
Private Sub CopyStep(wsOutp As Worksheet, ByVal sAdobeFile As String, ByVal sPath As String)

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink sPath & sAdobeFile
    AppActivate "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
    SendKeys "^a", True
    SendKeys "^c", True
    If Sheets("Menzis").Range("A1") = "" Then
        Sheets("Menzis").Activate
        Sheets("Menzis").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Else
        Sheets("Menzis").Activate
        Sheets("Menzis").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
    End If

End Sub
```

I get the error when I want to paste special. (both of them)

Comment: Can you put this line `Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#` before and after the `SendKeys` lines?

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `Sheets("Menzis").Range("A1").End(xlDown)` will result in the very last line of the worksheet if no data is **below A1**. Therefore you cannot `.Offset(1, 0)` one row further because you exceed the maximum row limit.

To find the last used row in a column better use the `xlUp` method:

```
Sheets("Menzis").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
```

and then offset

```
Sheets("Menzis").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

---

```
Private Sub CopyStep(wsOutp As Worksheet, ByVal sAdobeFile As String, ByVal sPath As String)
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink sPath & sAdobeFile
    AppActivate "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
    SendKeys "^a", True
    SendKeys "^c", True

    Sheets("Menzis").Activate 'not necessarily needed to paste
    Sheets("Menzis").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

If this still throws an error you need to add `Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#` before you paste as Vityata pointed out in his comment.

Comment: Thank you it worked, the problem was not with the row location but with the wait time

Comment: Still recommend the `xlUp` method as it is much more reliable than using `xlDown` which might fail depending on the data in column A.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#` before and after sending the keys like this:

```
Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#
SendKeys "^a", True
SendKeys "^c", True
Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#
```

makes sure that the action is actually performed and the application takes time to respond to it. This is why it worked with <kbd>F8</kbd>.